# Canvas coordinates inaccurately display my bitmap

Tags: java, android, coordinates, android-canvas, ondraw

**To those favoriting this Question, give it an upvote too**

I'm using a a class that extends `View`. In this class I have the `onDraw` method where I do my drawing.

When I launch my app, everything works as intended except for a little annoying thing.. whenever I press anywhere on my screen, the drawing, which calculates the coordinates of where I touched the screen - and is supposed to draw the image in those exact coordinates, draws them a little bit off of where I originally pressed.

For example, if I tap the screen at x = 150, y = 250, the image will be displayed off by a significant amount of pixels.

To be clear, when I press the screen, I want my image displayed exactly under my finger or in very close proximity to where I tapped it, however, the image is displayed usually 100 or so pixels below where the press occured.

Is there something that I do not know about coordinates when using a canvas to draw?

Here is my code

```
public class PixelParticle extends View{

    private float locationX;
    private float locationY;
    private int sizeX;
    private int sizeY;
    private Paint color;
    private Rect rect;
    private int paintcolor;
    private float myLocX;
    private float myLocY;


    public PixelParticle(Context context, float locationX, float locationY, int sizeX, int sizeY, int paintcolor) {
        super(context);

        this.locationX = locationX;
        this.locationY = locationY;
        this.sizeX = sizeX;
        this.sizeY = sizeY;
        this.paintcolor = paintcolor;

        rect = new Rect();
        color = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 250, 250, true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap,locationX ,locationY , null);
    }
}
```

And the MainActivity..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int pixelColor;
    private float x;
    private float y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

     @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();

            pixelColor = Color.RED;
            PixelParticle pp = new PixelParticle(this, x, y, 50, 50, pixelColor);
            setContentView(pp); 
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you handling `onTouchEvent` from your view?. I might be wrong, but maybe the coordinates reported by `MotionEvent` differ in View and Activity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the screen includes the title and the notification bar.
 Make the Activity Full Screen and remove the title will solve the issue.
Try this:

PixelParticle...

```
    public class PixelParticle extends View {

private float locationX;
private float locationY;
private int sizeX;
private int sizeY;
private Paint color;
private Rect rect;
private int paintcolor;
private float myLocX;
private float myLocY;

public PixelParticle(Context context, float locationX, float locationY,
        int sizeX, int sizeY, int paintcolor) {
    super(context);

    this.locationX = locationX;
    this.locationY = locationY;
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
    this.paintcolor = paintcolor;

    rect = new Rect();
    color = new Paint();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 250, 250,
            true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, locationX
            - (resizedBitmap.getWidth() / 2),
            locationY - (resizedBitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);

}}
```

MainActivity..

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int pixelColor;
private float x;
private float y;
PixelParticle pp ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();

        pixelColor = Color.RED;
         pp = new PixelParticle(this, x, y, 50, 50, pixelColor);
        setContentView(pp); 
        return false;
    }}
```

Comment: I love you, this works great! Just as I wanted it to. Now I'll play around with it to get a better handle on this.